# Изменение типа данных столбца postgreSql

Tags: sql, postgresql, типы

имеется столбец типа integer. Сейчас нужно заменить его на integer[].
Делаю

```
ALTER TABLE public.productgallery ALTER COLUMN genderid TYPE integer[]
USING genderid::integer[]
```

Но получаю ошибку - [42846] ERROR: cannot cast type integer to integer[] Position: 86. and 1 duplicate reports

Подскажите - в чём проблема?

Comment: В том, что невозможно привести скалярное значение к массиву.

Comment: Создайте новой поле с нужным (или временным) именем и нужным типом.  Выполните копирование данных в новое поле с соотв. преобразованием типа. Удалите старое поле. Если надо - переименуйте новое поле.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, тогда подскажите как мне реализовать мою задумку?

Comment: @Akina, спасибо, сейчас попробую

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам нужен чуть другой синтаксис, если вы хотите получить для старых строк массив с одним элементом - значением строки до смены типа:

```
ALTER TABLE productgallery ALTER COLUMN genderid TYPE integer[] using array[genderid];
```

Comment: Спасибо большое.